# Vagrant shared folder works for working directory, but none other

Tags: nfs, vagrant, shared-directory

Normally I am happy with the 'default' folder sharing line for Vagrant, where /vagrant in the guest box maps to your working directory.

```
config.vm.share_folder("v-root", "/vagrant", ".", :nfs => true)
```

However, in this particular case, I'm trying to create one VM for multiple repositories, so I'm trying to map a folder of the guest to another folder which isn't the working directory (.)

```
config.vm.share_folder("v-repos", "/projects", "~/Projects/", :nfs => true)
```

I've tried to map to '../' and varieties, and to absolute paths '/Users/dietervds/', and others, but I always receive the error:

> [default] Mounting NFS shared folders... Mounting NFS shared folders
>   failed. This is most often caused by the NFS client software not being
>   installed on the guest machine. Please verify that the NFS client
>   software is properly installed, and consult any resources specific to
>   the linux distro you're using for more information on how to do this.

However, since NFS works just fine for the default line, it must be something else.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance,

Dieter

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that ":nfs" is by default false.

Did you confirm, not assume, that the line below is working?

```
config.vm.share_folder("v-root", "/vagrant", ".", :nfs => true)
```

If that line has no errors, and another has... That is really strange.

Comment: Definitely `:nfs` is `false` by default. Look at the [source code](http://rubydoc.info/gems/vagrant/Vagrant/Config/VMConfig%3ashare_folder)

Comment: That line definitely works as an NFS share, I use it in all my Vagrant boxes. I have done my setup different since this post. Thanks in any case!